# How to fix, "Breakpoint installation failed: unmatched quote" when setting breakpoints in TrueSTUDIO for STM32

Tags: c, debugging, breakpoints, stm32, truestudio

After setting breakpoints in my code and then debugging, I am given the error stated in the question title and manually interrupting the program results in a console message, "No source available for "__muldf3() at 0x80006be" (as an example), possibly indicating that there is no debug source code to reference.

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding and restarting TrueSTUDIO. 
I have set my build configuration to debug.
I have made sure that the .elf file is correct.

I don't know why my debug source files might be unmatched with my build code. Is there something or some setting which I am neglecting to change?

Comment: you have stopped the code inside this function so it is very likely that it was in the library without the source code and debug information. Does it stop at the brkpts in your code? If not, didn't you pressed the button to ignore the breakpoints?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop at any breakpoints I set :/ I tried setting in my main and other function source files. None work, all give the same error.

Comment: can you set the breakpoint in the disassebly window?

Comment: Another clue - do you load the correct .elf? (Not form another project)

Comment: Yes, I can view the disassembly when manually interrupting program flow and it shows the breakpoint there.

Comment: I don't know how to be sure that it is the correct .elf file :/ all I know is that the name is correct

Comment: I am able to step through my code in the debugger perspective and inspect all elements, but breakpoints don't seem to want to work

Comment: check if you do not have active "skip all breakpoints"

Comment: definitely don't have that active

Answer (score 0):

__muldf3() and in fact, most if not all the symbols with double scores prefix are "internal functions known to the compiler". In this particular case __muldf3 multiplies double arguments. You get this particular error because you are "randomly" breaking the debugger so the program pauses at wherever point it was at. In this case, it happened to be inside __muldf3. Since the library source code is not available in your particular setup, you get the "no source" error.

As for the "Breakpoint attribute problem: installation failed", I have not seen this error myself, and certainly it's pretty opaque on what it is complaining about. Please check that you are doing a debug build, and please clarify whether the debugger stops at main (as it should), even with this error. Web searches indicate that this error could be ignored if it does not stop you from using the debugger otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed some of the earlier replies that indeed the debugger does not stops at any of the breakpoint. It is possible that the actual program has not been flashed onto the chip. Use ST's ST-LINK utility and does a verify with the project output to make sure indeed TrueStudio has done the flashing correctly.